# Tex align 2 figures on same line

Tags: formatting, wrapfigure

I have the following tex markup:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,total={170mm,257mm},left=20mm,top=20mm}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum{1-3}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5\textwidth}
   \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{./600x400.png}
   \end{center}
    \caption{Account data export in Diaspora* control panel}
    \label{DIASPORA:ACC:TRANSF}
\end{wrapfigure}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
   \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{./600x400_2.png}
    \end{center}
    \caption{Account Deletion in Diaspora* control panel}
    \label{DIASPORA:ACC:DEL}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum{5}
\end{document}
```

And the following result is generated in [pdf](http://pc-magas.github.io/dummy.pdf).

What I want to achieve it to place 2 wrapfigures next to each other like that:

[image: 2 wrapfigures placed next to each other]

Instead of this placement:
[image: Wrapficures places right now]

How I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XeLaTex this can get achieved via `figure` and `minipage` as this example shows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,total={170mm,257mm},left=20mm,top=20mm}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum{1-3}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
       \begin{center}
            % The line is as wide as is defined subpage.
            % Meaning the overall width of this section is 0.5*\textwith
            \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{./600x400.png}
       \end{center}
        \captionof{figure}{Account data export in Diaspora* control panel}
        \label{DIASPORA:ACC:TRANSF}
    \end{minipage}% 
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
       \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{./600x400_2.png}
        \end{center}
        \captionof{figure}{Account Deletion in Diaspora* control panel}
        \label{DIASPORA:ACC:DEL}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\lipsum{5-6}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\center` environment add unnecessary vertical space around images. better is replace it by `\centering` after `\begin{figure}`. also `\captionof` is superfluous` images are in `figure` environment. use of `\|lipsum{1-3}` is wrong, correct is `\lipsum[1-3]`.

Comment: beside mentioned in above code, your mwe doesn't work due to clash  with `graphicx` package. move it after `\usepackage{geometry}`

Comment: I build it using XeTeX did you try standart LaTeX?

Comment: it works only with xelatex (after mentioned correction).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `floatrow` package for this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,total={170mm,257mm},left=20mm,top=20mm}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering\floatsetup{floatrowsep=qquad}
\begin{floatrow}[2]
   \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-16x10.png}}
    {\caption{Account data export in Diaspora* control panel}
    \label{DIASPORA:ACC:TRANSF}}
   \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-16x10.png}}
{\caption{Account Deletion in Diaspora* control panel}
    \label{DIASPORA:ACC:DEL}}
    \end{floatrow}
\end{figure}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]